# How to display the title of a category based on its ID?

Tags: categories, filter, category, titles

I’m passing the ID of a category to a template via a `catId` query string (i.e. http://example.com/some/path?catId=10).

How do I display the title of that category?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you’ll need to grab the category ID from the query string, using [craft.request.getQuery()](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.request#getQuery):

```
{% set catId = craft.request.getQuery('catId') %}
```

Then you can fetch the [CategoryModel](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/categorymodel) via [craft.categories](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.categories) and its [id param](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.categories#id):

```
{% set category = craft.categories.id(catId).first() %}
```

We can’t be sure that the ID was actually valid, so make sure that `category` is actually set to something, otherwise return a 404 error:

```
{% if not category %}
    {% exit 404 %}
{% endif %}
```

Now, to output the category’s title, just do this:

```
{{ category.title }}
```

There are a couple ways you can put this all together, depending on whether the page **requires** a category ID passed to it, or if it’s optional.

If it’s required, we should verify that the `catId` query parameter was actually set to something right off the bat:

```
{% set catId = craft.request.getQuery('catId') %}

{# The catId param is required #}
{% if not catId %}
    {% exit 404 %}
{% endif %}

{% set category = craft.categories.id(catId).first() %}

{% if not category %}
    {% exit 404 %}
{% endif %}

{{ category.title }}
```

If it’s optional, then we should grab the ID from the query string, and then wrap all of the remaining logic in a conditional, so it only runs if there was an ID:

```
{% set catId = craft.request.getQuery('catId') %}

{# The catId param is optional #}
{% if catId %}
    {% set category = craft.categories.id(catId).first() %}

    {% if not category %}
        {% exit 404 %}
    {% endif %}

    {{ category.title }}
{% endif %}
```